# Route all traffic through TUN interface

Tags: networking, ip, routing, iptables, tunnel

I want all my traffic go through `TUN` interface.
[Here is the flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaSeW.png)

So, as you can see, the traffic is routed to `TUN` iface on `10.0.0.1` address from every program. Then, the program attached to the `TUN` does something with the packets, and then they are sent to my router on `192.168.1.1`. Then they're routed across the Internet (for example, to my proxy server, but it doesn't actually matter that much for my problem).

So my goal is just to route traffic in that manner: `$any_program` <--> `tunX` <--> `192.168.1.1 (the router)` (`<-->` thing means that traffic goes both in and out).

What I've did so far:

1. First, I initialized `tunX` device with this function:

```c
int tun_open(char *device)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;
    
    fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("opening /dev/net/tun");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name, device, IFNAMSIZ);
    
    err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr);
    if (err == -1)
    {
        perror("ioctl TUNSETIFF");
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    return fd;
}
```

And then:

```c
tunfd = tun_open("tun6");
```

Also, I enabled `TUNSETPERSIST`:

```c
ioctl(tunfd, TUNSETPERSIST, 1) < 0);
```

2. Then, I set up the device with following commands:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun6
$ sudo ip link set tun6 up
```

The program reads from `tunfd` and outputs the content. So far the only thing it reads is the following:

```
:B\{k
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover" 
MX: 1
ST: urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1
USER-AGENT: Google Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Linux

%   N%*.%K%M%P%M%M%M%HP%,%M%*K%(aP%>O%M%LqP%@K%`P%P%Ҵ u@=U繤湤}=UoK%0=U
```

ssdp:discover? Why is this getting through my tun interface?

Output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

I've been playing around with `iptables` and `ip route` programs, but I'm kind of a newbie in all these. As far as I understood, `iptables` doesn't actually route the packets, but filter them (I can be very wrong). So is there a way to route the packets with `ip route`?

Thanks for reading all of these n00b stuff that I've written here. Wish you could help me!

Comment: If you set your default gateway (destination `0.0.0.0`) to the tun interface instead of to wlp2s0, all traffic will go through the tun interface. Please don't use `iptables` for routing (this is a pet peeve of mine).

Comment: @dirkt okay! But then, how could I send traffic to the Internet, if everything will go to/from my tun interface by default? I want to go like program -> tun -> wlp2s0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all my traffic go through TUN interface.

If you set your default gateway (destination 0.0.0.0) to the tun interface instead of to wlp2s0, all traffic will go through the tun interface. Please don't use iptables for routing (this is a pet peeve of mine).

> But then, how could I send traffic to the Internet, if everything will go to/from my tun interface by default?

So you don't want **all** your traffic to go through the TUN interface.

If the program using tun is a real tunnel (VPN), you add an additional route to the other endpoint of the tunnel (look at what `openvpn` does, try `openvpn` with one of the many free VPNs and observe the routing table. The `0.0.0.0/1` and the `128.0.0.0/1` you'll see is a substitute for the default route, because that way they can keep the old default route).

If you want your TUN application to be some sort of proxy, and establish connections from the TUN application to everywhere in the internet, then you can't do that with routing. Either use a network namespace (then you can have two default routes), or you really need to use `iptables` and figure out some way to distinguish packets coming from your TUN application.

Comment: If I use a user network stack like lwip, after I write packet through tun, does the packet just go away from my computer, no routing decision in there?

Comment: If I write packet into tun device, How I avoid to read same packet which I just written avoiding dead loop

Comment: @nuclear please open up a question for new questions... you may reference this Q&A in your question.

Comment: I just make a question for you ;). Glad to hear you https://superuser.com/questions/1664065/tun-device-how-to-avoid-routing-dead-loop-when-write-a-transparent-proxy